# Oracle - Avoiding invalidation errors

Tags: sql, oracle

I've noticed that whenever I have package-level constants (or any variables for that matter), whenever I recompile the package, persistent connections to the database get an error that "existing state of package body has been invalidated".

Is there a way to avoid this? Perhaps through synonyms? What are best-practices in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is if, at 10:00am, a session starts and the constant is set to 'A', then at 11:00am you change it to 'B', then the session 'blows up' in confusion.

The [Serially_Reusable](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/package_declaration.htm#sthref2927) pragma may work for you. Basically it won't preserve state between calls. So at 11:0am it will just start using 'B'. If you can be 100% sure that won't break your code, it can work. Re-initializing the constants whenever they are needed may be an overhead.

Also look at calling [DBMS_SESSION.MODIFY_PACKAGE_STATE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sessio.htm#sthref5887) or [DBMS_SESSION.RESET_PACKAGE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sessio.htm#i1010767) at appropriate intervals. That may reduce the number of errors you get.

You should also look at [Edition-based redefinition](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/10-jan/o10asktom.html) in the new [11gR2](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10471/adfns_editions.htm#CHDFGIAA). That's a more comprehensive solution, but I guess you'd need to upgrade for that.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you should avoid replacing code in a live production instance.

If you really **really** have to be live 24/24 7/7, and you can't schedule ANY (even tiny) downtime you will have to avoid package-level variables since recompilation of a such a package will trigger the aforementionned error.

You could also catch the error in your **client** application and decide what to do. Maybe you have sufficient information to restart whatever the client was doing.

#### See also

> This [thread on AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3516589324948#35495998991125) covers the same topic.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've gotten around this by moving all state-related stuff into separate packages.

For example, if I had a package "CUSTOMER_PKG", I'd move all the global variables into a spec-only package called "CUSTOMER_GLOBALS_PKG".

Unfortunately this means exposing all private globals that were defined in the package body. We had to enforce a development standard so that CUSTOMER_GLOBALS_PKG was only allowed to be referred to by CUSTOMER_PKG.